# When SQL Server bcps into an empty table with an index what does it do internally?

Tags: sql-server, indexing, bcp

If I have an empty table with an index and I do a bcp, does SQL Server (internally) drop/disable the index, load the data and then re-apply/enable/build the index?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, the indexes are maintained throughout the operation. In fact, Microsoft says you can improve bcp performance by using the `-h ORDER` hint to sort the data according to your clustered index. See the [bcp Utility documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) for details. However, as stated [here](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/tips/bcp_p1.aspx), for the fastest import possible you should take the following steps:

> ·         The "select into/bulkcopy"
>   database option must be set to "true".
>
> ·         **The target table should not
>   have any indexes.** [emphasis added]
>
> ·         The target table must not be
>   published for replication.
>
> ·         Use the TABLOCK to lock the
>   target table.

Answer (score 3):

No it doesn't but it will do its best to make it as fast as possible. Also you can help a little bit too by following some basic guidelines (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177445.aspx).